# $D\subset U\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ compact domain, $\left.f\right|_{\partial D}\equiv 0 \implies \int_{D}\det f'(x)=0$

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, pullback

Let $U$ an open set in $\Bbb{R}^m$, $f:U\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^m$ a $C^2$ map. Let $D\subset U$ a compact domain, with $C^2$ boundary $\partial D$. If $\left.f\right|_{\partial D}\equiv 0$, so $\int_{D}J(x)=0$, where $J(x)=\det f'(x)$.

$D$ is a compact domain, that is, $D$ is a compact surface with boundary. Since $\partial D$ is $C^2$, $D$ is $C^3$.

My problem here is that $J$ and $f$ are not differential forms. I want to apply the Stokes Theorem, but I dont know how.

What I tried: Let $\omega$ the volume form in $\Bbb{R}^m$. So $f^{*}\omega$ is a differential form in $U$. By hypothesis, $\left.f\right|_{\partial D}\equiv 0\implies \left.f^{*}\omega\right|_{\partial D}\equiv 0$. So, we have

$$\int_{\partial D}f^{*}\omega=0. $$

But, by Stokes theorem,

$$\int_{\partial D}f^{*}\omega=\int_{D}d(f^{*}\omega)=\int_{D}f^{*}(d\omega). $$

That is all that I got. I dont know if I am in the right way.

Comment: $\omega$, and thus $f^*\omega$, is an $m$-form, so the integral $\int_{\partial D} f^*\omega$ does not make much sense. But the idea is in the right direction: just begin the integration with a primitive $\eta$ of $\omega$ instead.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo what do you mean by "primitive"?

Comment: A form $\eta$ for which $d\eta=\omega$.

Comment: But the volume form is not exact

Comment: It is exact. Specifically, you can take $\eta:=\sum_{i=1}^m\epsilon_ix_idx_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{dx_i}\wedge \cdots\wedge dx_m$, for example, where $\epsilon_i=(-1)^{i+1}/m$. If you do not wish to be explicit, this is a direct consequence of Poincaré's lemma.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Just one term, no sum?